# std::vector do not support rvalue assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Here's the my test code:

```
void Test::test(const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    data = std::move(buffer);
}
```

this code seems meaningless, it's just a example.
I use code navigation in my ide to find out the implementation of the = operator, I found out that the turely one handled is the `operator=(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x)`, which is doing the copy job.

I searched the whole file, there's no funtion like `operator=(vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&& __x)`, so how can I benefit from the move and rvalue featrue?

My c++ header is in `/usr/include/c++/5` and the file I checked is `vector.tcc`.

Answer (score 6):

It does support move assignment, but you are attempting to abuse it. You accept `buffer` by a const reference. Move assignment requires modifying the **source**. Your compiler is trying to tell you that.

The quick fix is to accept by a non-const reference. The better fix would be to accept `buffer` by an rvalue reference already. That way the caller is not doomed to be astonished when their vector's content is stolen.

The *even better* fix is to accept by value. That way the caller has full control over how the passed buffer is created. And your function is usable in more instances.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did do this for a purpose. But how about the “no move assignment version” thing?  Am I searching for the wrong file?

Comment: @reavenisadesk - Possibly. You didn't specify your compiler or build flags. So no telling really.